# NodeJS and Redis : getting three values simultaneously

Tags: node.js, redis, get, node-redis

currently I do this for getting many values in NodeJS and Redis with node-redis :

```
redis.get('data1', function(err, data1)
{ 
     redis.get('data2', function(err, data2)
     {
         redis.get('data3', function(err, data3)  
         {

              if (data3 == xx && data2 == xx && data3 == xx)
              { 
                  console.log('its ok'); 
              }

          });
      });
});
```

The problem is that the three request will be one after another, I want to make 3 at once, and then call my condition like this for example (this don't work it's just for you understand what I want) :

```
redis.get('data1', function(err, data1) { var data1 = data1; });
redis.get('data2', function(err, data2) { var data2 = data2; });
redis.get('data3', function(err, data3) { var data3 = data3; });
// When the 3 get operations was finished 
if (data3 == xx && data2 == xx && data3 == xx)
{ 
    console.log('its ok'); 
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `mget` or `batch`.

```
redis.mget(['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], cb);
```

or

```
redis.batch().get('data1').get('data2').get('data3').exec(cb);
```

Answer (score 16):

[MGET](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/d25d12eee7fa14b249d7ce82fee5c47cce5eea75/examples/mget.js) will probably be the fastest, instead of going back and forth 3 times:

```
client.mget(["data1", "data2", "data3"], function (err, res) {
    console.dir(res);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Small update, maybe it will help someone avoid some frustration - in node-redis v4 some non-backwards compatible changes were implemented and, for example, `.mget` method has been changed to `.mGet`. See eg: 
https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/1765 
https://github.com/redis/node-redis/releases

Also now methods return Promises by default so async/await can be used instead of callbacks:

```
async testFunc() {
    const values = ["first", "some", "second", "test", "third", "values"];
    const mSetResult = await client.mSet(values);
    console.log(mSetResult); // OK
    const mGetResult = await client.mGet(["first", "second", "fourth", "third"]);
    console.log(mGetResult); // [ 'some', 'test', null, 'values' ]
}

await testFunc();
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible (but rather popular) ways is to use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module like so:

```
async.map(['data1','data2','data3'], redis.get, function (err, results) {
  if (err) { return; }
  // results is now an array
});
```